# google apps script - how to exclude part of the code which returns error (502 Bad Gateway)

Tags: google-apps-script, error-checking

I've got a code that scraps few websites using UrlFetchApp.fetch and JSON.parse methods. Lately I'm getting a lot of errors when one of the websites is down so the whole code stops from execution.

Is there a way to check the execution results of particular parts of the code prior to the final execution of the whole code and then using IF statement to exclude from execution that part of the code which returned error?

Comment: What you want is most likely a try-catch. Try to look up Exception Handling to Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass {muteHttpExceptions:true} to UrlFetchApp.fetch(). In this case full response will be returned even if status is not 200.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{ muteHttpExceptions: true});
```